# ios tabbar put text in the middle when no image

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

My tabbar consists only of text, no images.
The problem is that the text always show on the bottom of the tab, is there a way to position the text in the middle ?

Thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Got it!

`[tab.tabBarItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -10)]`

Comment: I am trying same thing, but its not working. Do we have to do anything else also ?

Comment: No that's it. Where are you putting it ?

Comment: Why (0, -10)? I don't understand... Can you explain me?

Comment: based on the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIOffset the UIOffset  `are positive for right or down, negative for left or up.`, by default iOS considers there's an image so puts the text in the bottom, what we want is to lift the text. the value 10 is by trial and error :)

Answer (score 5):

A supplement, if you set multi viewControllers in tabBarController, you should use the following:

```
for (UITabBarItem* item in tabBarController.tabBar.items)
{
    [item setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -10)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift update.

```
func tabBarItem(title: String, imageName: String, selectedImageName: String, tagIndex: Int) -> UITabBarItem {
        let item = UITabBarItem(title: title,
                                image: UIImage(named: imageName),
                                selectedImage: UIImage(named: selectedImageName))
        item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal:0, vertical:-10)
        item.tag = tagIndex
        return item
    }
```

// For example

```
let window = UIWindow.window()
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.tabBarItem = tabBarItem(title: "More", imageName: "icon_more", selectedImageName: "icon_more", tagIndex: 1)


let mainTBC = UITabBarController()
    mainTBC.viewControllers = [vc]
 window?.rootViewController = mainTBC
 window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```