# Swift: Is there a way to make a text only tab bar?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I know how to make the Tab Bar with image and text and even know how to change the image insets to make a tab only an image. However, I am having a problem trying to do text only. I want to be able to adjust text to center and change style/height of text. Just want to make sure before I make an image that there is not an easier way.

Edit: Looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586411/ios-tabbar-put-text-in-the-middle-when-no-image)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove the images in the UITabBarItem and aligned vertically the title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248457/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-images-in-the-uitabbaritem-and-aligned-vertically-t)

Comment: That is essentially my question, however, I was hoping I was missing a checkmark or something in interface builder. Rob always gives a 100 line code answer. Maybe it's my only option though =\ . Thanks

Comment: @Larme after further reading the link in comments. Rob says himself its probably easier to just use photoshop or something to make the image. I was looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586411/ios-tabbar-put-text-in-the-middle-when-no-image) for Swift. I feel this is pretty ridiculous just to align some text.